# How to keep Roku from entering screen saver mode

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I have written an audio player for Roku using the SceneGraph and BrightScript. The way it works is as follows:
I have an  node on the MainScene. All of the audio is played through this node.
I have a custom node (AudioProvider) that I wrote that grabs, from a server, the necessary information needed to play a track of audio and provides that information to another custom node (AudioService) that turns the track information into a ContentNode and sets it as the Audio node's content.
This works great until the Roku starts the screen saver. Once that happens, it will finish the current track and stop.

So....how do I get around this?

I have implemented the solution laid out [here](https://community.roku.com/t5/Roku-Developer-Program/Is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-prevent-Roku-to-go-to-screen/m-p/326075) to no avail (granted it's nearly a decade old). I think I'm actually just doing something wrong b/c this requirement seems like it would be fairly standard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 3):

Probably You're using the `Audio` node, which doesn't have the interface You need here. Try to use `Video` node instead, and it's interfaces `enableScreenSaverWhilePlaying` and `disableScreenSaver`.
More info here: https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/references/scenegraph/media-playback-nodes/video.md#miscellaneous-fields